# Migrate method setLatestEventInfo to API 23+

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications

Currently I'm running with new environment in Android. Unfortunately, previous developer before I joined, it seems he using API 22. So, this is about legacy.

Now I have several issue in Notification, since `setLatestEventInfo` was removed (for 23+). I face with challenge to migrate past method. Here my code:

```
/depreciation/
@protected void PushNotification(String title, String message) {

String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
CharSequence tickerText = message;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
Context context = this;
CharSequence contentTitle = title;
CharSequence contentText = message;
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

Need suggest to do the right thing, several opinion suggest to adding `NotificationCompat` but I don't know how to do or any alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try use NotificationCompat.Builder